# Jquery double click in form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have problem with form , for send i need do double click over submit bottom , i use function for send the form , the script i create it´s this :

```
<script>
function pin_login(forma) {
    jQuery("#form_"+forma).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var value_pin=jQuery(".pin_"+forma).val();
        var value_cookie=$.cookie(''+forma);
        var deco=base64_decode(''+value_cookie);

        if (value_pin==deco) {
            $.cookie('access_'+forma, 'ok', { expires: 14 });
            jQuery("#cp_request_pin_ok").show(500);
            setTimeout("location.href='?action=cp'",1500);
        } else {
            jQuery("#cp_request_pin_fail").show(500);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And the Form :

```
<form id="form_v" name="form" method="post" action="?" onsubmit="pin_login('v');return false;">
    <input name="pin_vps" type="text" class="pin_vps" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Access" />
</form>
```

How i can fix this for works when submit in one only click ? , Thank´s , Regards !!!

Answer (score 0):

First you will want to change your markup. Use a `button` instead of an `input` so we don't have to deal with the form submitting that way.

Second you can typically use something like this:

```
$('#submit').dblclick( function() {
    $('#form_v').submit();
});
```

Here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cYAea/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using ajax form to submit forms, which is very easy to use and a good scope of functions available.. Example here..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('form').ajaxForm({
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#myID').text($(data).find('#Id').text()); //finding #Id value from response markup
                    $('#myID2').text($(data).find('#id2>').text());
                    $('#newPara').show();
                    $('#text').text('Response using Ajax');
                }
            });
        });
```

You can download the Jquery form pugin from here,
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
there are many examples given in the site as well..